# Change the colour of a cell if the user changes the content of that cell

Tags: vba, excel

Trying to change the color of a cell, if the user changes the cell. At the moment it changes the next cell I select after I change some content.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Environ("Username") = "HelloWorld" Then
    With ActiveCell.Interior
        .Pattern = xlSolid
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 7195899
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: change `With ActiveCell.Interior` to `With Target.Interior` , as you are passing the `ActiveCell` as `Target` to `Worksheet_Change` event

Answer (score 1):

You just need to change "ActiveCell.Interior" to "Target.Interior":

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Environ("Username") = "HelloWorld" Then
    With Target.Interior
        .Pattern = xlSolid
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 7195899
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With
End If
End Sub
```

This is because this sub is triggered after you change any cell, so the "ActiveCell" referenced differs from "Target".

Happy coding!

Comment: Wow, such an easy solution! My only problem is it now removes the capacity to undo

Comment: As far as I know all macros remove the capacity to undo, would you like to undo just the cell format? Perhaps you could add some conditions on the code to prevent certain things you wish to avoid so there's no need to undo. Or you could use conditional formating with a formula as a condition, and save the username in a "VeryHidden" worksheet, so that the user can't modify it. Then you can reference this condition to the username.

Comment: Yeah, it is just much less user friendly if you cannot undo, if users make an error, then they cannot press undo.